How to proof spectrum replication algebraically?
I understand the implication of Nyquist frequency or aliasing but I couldn't derive it algebraically. Let's start from the simplest form of phasor representation $e^{j \theta}$ and expand it based on the periodicity of phasor:
$$
\begin{align}
e^{j\theta_n} 
&= e^{j(\theta_n + k 2\pi)} \\ 
&= e^{j (\omega_0 t_n + k 2\pi)} \\
&= e^{j (\omega_0 n T_s + k 2\pi)} \\
&= e^{j nT_s(\omega_0 + {k \over n} {2\pi \over T_s})} \\
&= e^{j nT_s(\omega_0 + {k \over n} \omega_s)} \\
\end{align}
$$
$ k \over n$ does not guarantee integer multiple. The result couldn't be correct but I see nothing wrong with the algebraic derivation.
To show aliasing the way it is defined and observed, the derivation from $ e^{j\theta_n} $ should end up to be
$$
e^{j (\omega_0 n T_s + nk \cdot 2\pi)} = e^{j n T_s (\omega_0 + {k \cdot 2\pi \over T_s})} = e^{j n T_s (\omega_0 + {k \omega_s})}
$$
To go from $ e^{j (\omega_0 n T_s + k \cdot 2\pi)} $ to $ e^{j n T_s (\omega_0 + {k \omega_s})} $ require adding in an extra $ n$ to the $ k 2 pi $ and make it a $ nk2pi $.  But that's not an algebraic proof. Just because both $n$ and $k$ are integers doesn't mean we can freely expand or decompose $n$ to $nk$, or we might as well stuff in another integer $m$ there and make it $nmk$ which is not proper.
So my question is how to proof spectrum replication exist by pure algebraic manipulation? In other words how to go from:
$$
e^{j \theta_n} \,\, \xrightarrow{\,\,\,\,\,\text{?}\,\,\,\,\,} \,\,e^{j n T_s (\omega_0 + {k \omega_s})}
$$
There is a closely related question: Understanding the mathematical proof for the alias frequencies in a sampled sine wave but it assumes aliasing $ f_0 = f_0 + kf_s $ exists in the first place before deriving the equation. I wanted to "rediscover" the replication of the signal spectrum by pure algebraic manipulation from $e^{j \theta} $ or $ \cos(\theta + \phi) $.

First you have to understand where images come from.  Then you have to understand that when adjacent images overlap, that's where aliasing comes from.

The images or the spectrum replica is a mathematical consequence of Fourier Transform. And the link also show how the pulse train become $k$ multiple $f_s$ not $nk$ multiples.  I still don't see how can there be an extra $ n $ in the $nk$ yet without that $n$ the equation is not valid, but I can't derive that algebraically. I realized I termed a few things incorrectly and have amended the question.

What's $n$? Is it not discrete time?

The equation
$$x[n]=e^{jn\omega_0T_s}=e^{jnT_s(\omega_0+k\omega_s/n)},\qquad\omega_s=\frac{2\pi}{T_s},\;k\in\mathbb{Z}\tag{1}$$
is correct. However, it doesn't directly show you frequencies that the original frequency $\omega_0$ could be confused with due to aliasing. The term $k\omega_s/n$ isn't a fixed set of frequencies (depending on $k$) because it also depends on the index $n$. For each sample $x[n]$ you get another value for $k\omega_s/n$. Hence, this representation is useless if we want to find frequencies that are mapped to $\omega_0$ due to sampling with sampling rate $\omega_s$.
In order to find those frequencies, we can rewrite $x[n]$ as follows:
$$x[n]=e^{jn\omega_0T_s}=e^{jn(\omega_0T_s+2\pi k)}=e^{jnT_s(\omega_0+k\omega_s)}\tag{2}$$
From $(2)$ it is clear that the frequencies $\omega_0+k\omega_s$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be distinguished from each other.

I guess there is no way to deduce the result algebraically from a general phasor without already assuming periodicity of sampling frequency or without forcefully adding an n to make the equation valid to a preexisting assumption.  So algebra is just the incorrect approach. The formula can only really be explained as a consequence from the math we use, the convolution where the FT or the spectrum is multiplied by the pulse train in the frequency domain, hence getting shifted at each integer multiple of the sampling frequency.
